# Heroku Status=500 Without Further Error Explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed an update (which works perfectly on `localhost`) to Heroku and I'm getting a `status=500` error in my logs, a `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` page for my index page, and no further information.

Here is the information from `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 3733, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3205/3205), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3733/3733), 7.43 MiB | 1.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 3733 (delta 943), reused 2943 (delta 463)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repository
remote:        It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
remote:        as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
remote:        not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
remote:        remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using rake 11.1.2
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Using google-analytics-rails 1.1.0
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using mime-types 3.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Using figaro 1.0.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.6
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.6
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.6
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.6
remote:        Using railties 4.2.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Using simple_form 3.2.1
remote:        Using mail_form 1.5.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing responders 2.2.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.6
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Installing jquery-turbolinks 2.1.0
remote:        Installing devise 4.2.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 58 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development, test and production were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (4.42s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.2.4'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repository
remote:        It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
remote:        as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
remote:        not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
remote:        remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 182.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v20
remote:        https://frozen-lowlands-30190.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-lowlands-30190.git
   5f16820..3583a96  master -> master
```

And here's the `status=500` line I get, which doesn't have further explanation:

```
2016-09-07T21:43:17.513968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.geneticgolf.com request_id=e52af315-b9c6-4029-af51-69deada5b2f3 fwd="70.181.88.50" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

I have run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart`, but to no avail. I also have the `rails_12factor` gem installed in my production group gemfile already.

Can anyone point out where the error might be or how to fix it?  The site is live so an erroring `index` page is bad...

**NEW INFORMATION**

The staging link for my site is apparently not exhibiting this problem, only the domain name that points to the staging link.

Comment: Read an error:
Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Comment: @mateo Thanks! I will fix this, but it says it's not the problem now, so I'm still floundering on this error...

Comment: @mateo The reason I know it was a status 500 was from the heroku logs. That was where the line beginning with today's date came from

Comment: according to this article the recommended web server is `Puma` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server. that should fix your issue regarding `Procfile`

Comment: @mrvncaragay, I can try `Puma`, but that error has existed since I first deployed the app through many successful deployments and is not causing this error.

Comment: i see, then that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @mrvncaragay All it's giving me in `heroku logs` when I try to load the index page is `2016-09-07T23:06:47.187552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.geneticgolf.com request_id=03e2f909-91f1-4dba-99c0-e590f9729d0e fwd="70.181.88.50" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=176ms status=500 bytes=1754`

Comment: Try restarting dynos once if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messaged Heroku support and they said that I should remove `.bundle/config` from my `Git` files because it was preventing my `production` gems from being installed, which prohibited `rails_12factor` from giving me information about the error.  Once this change was made the `heroku logs` actually began yielding useful information and I was able to debug.